# Where is the best place to buy images for a company logo?

Tags: logo

I am looking to purchase images to make a company logo and wondering where is the best place to source these

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to purchase images to make a company **[LOGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo)** ?

Are you sure you don't want to say banner? If a logo is really what you want to create then DON'T use images. A logo should be an act of creation, be it a symbol, typographic or a combination of the two and it should deeply reflect the business's activity. It should be VECTOR, therefore no purchased (raster) images should be involved.

Comment: We are opening a play area for kids with an Ark theme and were thinking of putting an Ark in the logo? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Lisa Using an image/photograph(raster image) for that is wrong. You could hire a designer to create a logo with a drawn Ark or integrated somehow in the name of the play area. But using an image for that is wrong.  You basically need a vector drawing/illustration for a logo.

Comment: https://graphicriver.net/category/logo-templates?term=ark and you're done